# Twig optionally namespaced templates

Tags: php, namespaces, twig

In Twig, is there a possibility to use namespaced template paths (e.g. `@admin/index.twig`) only when needed?

My setup looks like this:

- project X has a `template` directory
- project X has a dependency Y which has another `template` directory
- Twig is set up with both directories as template paths (first project X, then dependency Y)
- if project X wants to override a template supplied by dependency Y (e.g. `vendor/company/dependencyY/templates/navigation.twig`, it just has to create the template in its own directory `templates/navigation.twig`

It gets problematic, when we want to override a file using the `extends` keyword:

```
{# templates/navigation.twig #}

{% extends 'templates/navigation.twig' %}
{# meant to extend the dependency's template #}

{% block javascript %}
  {{ parent() }}
  <script src="...">
{% endblock %}
```

This obviously results in an infinite loop, as it tries to extend itself. To solve this problem, I can use namespaced templates, e.g. instead of `extends 'templates/navigation.twig'` I write `extends '@dependency/templates/navigation.twig'` (if twig is configured accordingly). This works.

But now I need to add the namespace `@dependency/` to all other `include` and `extends` statements or Twig won't find the templates anymore. If I do that, the template above `templates/navigation.twig` will not be called anymore, because it is not in the `@dependency/` namespace.

How to deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, sometimes typing the question triggers the right thoughts.

I was able to fix the problem with specifying the same template path in multiple namespaces:

```php
// register the directories with no namespace
$loader->addPath(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'templates');
$loader->addPath(DEPENDENCY_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'templates');

// register the dependency directory with a namespace
$loader->addPath(DEPENDENCY_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'templates', 'dependency');
```

This allows both `include "dependency_template.twig"` as well as `include "@dependency/dependency_template.twig"`. Or to quote the question: `@dependency/templates/navigation.twig`.

[Twig docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html#built-in-loaders)